# Cheap Mobile Data Sim Card for Short Stay in Amsterdam, Netherlands

Tags: cellphones, netherlands, internet, amsterdam, mobile-operators

I'm going to visit Amsterdam end of the June for 5 days. I have managed to find out Libra Mobile and Lyca Mobile has the cheapest Mobile Data offering.

- What is the best option to have for mobile data?
- Can I buy it at AMS airport?
- What are the documents needed?
- I have mobile phone (iPhone SE Unlocked) from Sri Lanka and will it work with Netherland 4G bands?

Comment: What phone do you use?

Comment: @Ulkoma iPhone SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my a bit opinionated answers:

- Libra or Lyca doesn't matter (prices https://www.bellen.com/vergelijken/prepaid, price will go up if you want 4G speed)
- You can just pick up sim card from any gsm shops for free, but at the airport, you might pay for that
- No documents needed
- It will work without any problem unless your phone is locked to the provider

Comment: If you arrive during day or early evening, look into the shops at the outside of the airport area but within the same complex. Schiphol (Amsterdam Airport) has a fair shopping mall for local use at the airport.

Comment: Can you please explain me `Libra or Lyca doesn't matter`?

Comment: Lyca and/or Lebara will require settings, I am familiar with the ones in the UK: Lebara need and APN to work, Lyca might work out of the box on 3G but APN settings are need to connect to 4G

Comment: Lyca also requires APN

Comment: Prices are really similar for these two providers

Comment: There is Libra sim shop Amsterdam Central to Dam Square street. Sim cards also available in SPAR supermarkets around €4.89